# Changed my DHCP settings specifically my router gateway ip now I can't access the internet and the gateway

Tags: dhcp

I changed my default gateway from `192.168.254.254` to `192.168.1.1`. Now it has no internet and I can't access the router itself. I tried pinging 2 pc's inside the `LAN` but it gave off the error

```
"DESTINATION HOST UNREACHABLE"
```

I also pinged the router with the same result. Any device I connect to. shows

```
"Unidentified network"
```

whether it's wireless or wired.

I've tried setting up a static IP on my computer but that didn't fix it either. I'm honestly out of options as I searched entire forums looking for a fix. Resetting the router isn't an option for some reason, I'd be grateful if someone could help me out

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh ok, so i figured it out when i was simulating the problem with another router.

It turns out that my DHCP server and Gateway were conflicting because they had different IP addresses and i fixed it up by setting the gateway in the ipv4 settings with the same IP address my DHCP server is showing in the control panel, now i can access the web interface again